# How to determine if a point is within a shape in a shapefile?

Tags: c#, gis

I have a shapefile defining shapes to cover a city. I also have a set of coordinates defined by latitude and longitude.

I need to be able to determine if these points are within any of the shapes in the shapefile.

Currently I'm trying to use easygis.net to figure this out, but it doesn't seem to be working.

I believe the coordinates in the shapefile are in UTM but have an offset northing, and I don't know how to correct it, translate it to lat/long, or convert my lat/long pairs to match.

I've been looking at other libraries like dotspatial and sharpmap, but I don't see intuitive answer to the problem.

At the same time, I'm sure this is a problem that has been solved. Are there any libraries that do this easily? Or how do I convert the offset UTM of the map to lat/long, or my lat/long points to this offset UTM?

Comment: you data is for northern hemisphere or southern?

Comment: Northern hemisphere. The easting seems correct, but the northing places the location at 1 degree latitude, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Or how do I convert the offset UTM of the map to lat/long, or my lat/long points to this offset UTM?

This requires reprojecting your points (or the shapefile's data).  This can be done via [Proj4Net](http://proj4net.codeplex.com/) (unless your GIS already supports it).

Once that's done, then it's a point in polygon test.  There are [many options for this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/218081/65358), though I often use the [winding number method](http://geomalgorithms.com/a03-_inclusion.html).

Comment: I'm pretty positive this is going to work, but I'm having problems with the transform. I read in the WKT from the projection file, then create a transformer from WGS84 to the read in projection. Pop my lat/long coords into the transformer and it should work. Right? Instead I'm getting coords that are way off.

Answer (score 9):

Here is some sample code on how you might use DotSpatial to firstly handle reprojection and secondly to test whether points are in a polygon, using the Contains method.

```
    public bool PointInShape() {
        // Load a shapefile.  If the shapefile is already using your custom projection, we don't need to change it.
        Shapefile wierdShapefile = Shapefile.OpenFile("C:\\MyShapefile.shp");

        // Note, if your shapefile with custom projection has a .prj file, then we don't need to mess with defining the projection.
        // If not, we can define the projection as follows:

        // First get a ProjectionInfo class for the normal UTM projection
        ProjectionInfo pInfo = DotSpatial.Projections.KnownCoordinateSystems.Projected.UtmNad1983.NAD1983UTMZone10N;

        // Next modify the pINfo with your custom False Northing
        pInfo.FalseNorthing = 400000;

        wierdShapefile.Projection = pInfo;

        // Reproject the strange shapefile so that it is in latitude/longitude coordinates
        wierdShapefile.Reproject(DotSpatial.Projections.KnownCoordinateSystems.Geographic.World.WGS1984);

        // Define the WGS84 Lat Lon point to test
        Coordinate test = new Coordinate(-120, 40);

        foreach (Feature f in wierdShapefile.Features) {
            Polygon pg = f.BasicGeometry as Polygon;
            if (pg != null)
            {
                if (pg.Contains(new Point(test)))
                {
                    // If the point is inside one of the polygon features
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else {
                // If you have a multi-part polygon then this should also handle holes I think
                MultiPolygon polygons = f.BasicGeometry as MultiPolygon;
                if (polygons.Contains(new Point(test))) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: This is pretty close to what I ended up implementing.

Comment: Cool =).  I wanted other folks that stumbled on this to have a code example.  If speed gives you a problem (for instance slow loading of Features) I think you can do Intersect testing with the shapes themselves.  Shapes only load the vectors and don't require the shapefile to read all the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to transform your projected file into a geographic coordinate, then Qgis is the easiest tool to use in my opinion, its is a lightweight GRASS based GIS software free and open. With straight forward projection tools.
http://www.qgis.org/

Comment: Thanks. I've taken a look but I'm not sure it meets my requirements. I don't see an API on the site, and I don't see something that I could interface with C#. I did manage to get this working with DotSpatial and Proj.Net.